# qmake clucene-core-2.3.3.4 errors

Tags: boost, zlib, clucene

ok i really need more spicific instruction on how to compile clucene in cmake wizard by qt5 creator i managed to download the clucene source code by git then i run cmake wizard from qt and it found the two compilers gcc and g++ but still could not find the boost and the zlib as it and this is the results :

```
ZLIB not found, using local: E:/qtproject/clucene/clucene/src/ext/zlib
Boost not found, using local: E:/qtproject/clucene/clucene/src/ext-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.7.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.7.2
-- Check for working C compiler: e:/Qt/Qt5.0.1/Tools/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: e:/Qt/Qt5.0.1/Tools/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: e:/Qt/Qt5.0.1/Tools/MinGW/bin/g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: e:/Qt/Qt5.0.1/Tools/MinGW/bin/g++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Checking to see if CXX compiler accepts flag -pg
-- Checking to see if CXX compiler accepts flag -pg - yes
-- Could NOT find Boost
-- Could NOT find ZLIB (missing:  ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Looking for include files sys/time.h, time.h
-- Looking for include files sys/time.h, time.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include stdlib.h
-- Looking for C++ include stdlib.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include stdarg.h
-- Looking for C++ include stdarg.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include stdio.h
-- Looking for C++ include stdio.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include stddef.h
-- Looking for C++ include stddef.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include ctype.h
-- Looking for C++ include ctype.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include algorithm
-- Looking for C++ include algorithm - found
-- Looking for C++ include functional
-- Looking for C++ include functional - found
-- Looking for C++ include map
-- Looking for C++ include map - found
-- Looking for C++ include vector
-- Looking for C++ include vector - found
-- Looking for C++ include list
-- Looking for C++ include list - found
-- Looking for C++ include set
-- Looking for C++ include set - found
-- Looking for C++ include math.h
-- Looking for C++ include math.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include fcntl.h
-- Looking for C++ include fcntl.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include limits.h
-- Looking for C++ include limits.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include string.h
-- Looking for C++ include string.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include sys/time.h
-- Looking for C++ include sys/time.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include memory.h
-- Looking for C++ include memory.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include sys/types.h
-- Looking for C++ include sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include stdint.h
-- Looking for C++ include stdint.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include unistd.h
-- Looking for C++ include unistd.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include io.h
-- Looking for C++ include io.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include direct.h
-- Looking for C++ include direct.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include sys/dir.h
-- Looking for C++ include sys/dir.h - not found
-- Looking for C++ include sys/ndir.h
-- Looking for C++ include sys/ndir.h - not found
-- Looking for C++ include dirent.h
-- Looking for C++ include dirent.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include wctype.h
-- Looking for C++ include wctype.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include stat.h
-- Looking for C++ include stat.h - not found
-- Looking for C++ include sys/stat.h
-- Looking for C++ include sys/stat.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include stdexcept
-- Looking for C++ include stdexcept - found
-- Looking for C++ include errno.h
-- Looking for C++ include errno.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include windef.h
-- Looking for C++ include windef.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include windows.h
-- Looking for C++ include windows.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include wchar.h
-- Looking for C++ include wchar.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include hash_map
-- Looking for C++ include hash_map - found
-- Looking for C++ include hash_set
-- Looking for C++ include hash_set - found
-- Looking for C++ include ext/hash_map
-- Looking for C++ include ext/hash_map - found
-- Looking for C++ include tr1/unordered_set
-- Looking for C++ include tr1/unordered_set - found
-- Looking for C++ include tr1/unordered_map
-- Looking for C++ include tr1/unordered_map - found
-- Looking for C++ include sys/timeb.h
-- Looking for C++ include sys/timeb.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include tchar.h
-- Looking for C++ include tchar.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include strings.h
-- Looking for C++ include strings.h - found
-- Looking for C++ include sys/mman.h
-- Looking for C++ include sys/mman.h - not found
-- Looking for C++ include winerror.h
-- Looking for C++ include winerror.h - found
-- Choosing type for int8_t
-- Check size of int8_t
-- Check size of int8_t - done
-- Choosing type for int8_t - signed int8_t
-- Choosing type for uint8_t
-- Check size of uint8_t
-- Check size of uint8_t - done
-- Choosing type for uint8_t - unsigned uint8_t
-- Choosing type for int16_t
-- Check size of int16_t
-- Check size of int16_t - done
-- Choosing type for int16_t - signed int16_t
-- Choosing type for uint16_t
-- Check size of uint16_t
-- Check size of uint16_t - done
-- Choosing type for uint16_t - unsigned uint16_t
-- Choosing type for int32_t
-- Check size of int32_t
-- Check size of int32_t - done
-- Choosing type for int32_t - signed int32_t
-- Choosing type for uint32_t
-- Check size of uint32_t
-- Check size of uint32_t - done
-- Choosing type for uint32_t - unsigned uint32_t
-- Choosing type for int64_t
-- Check size of int64_t
-- Check size of int64_t - done
-- Choosing type for int64_t - signed int64_t
-- Choosing type for uint64_t
-- Check size of uint64_t
-- Check size of uint64_t - done
-- Choosing type for uint64_t - unsigned uint64_t
-- Choosing type for size_t
-- Check size of size_t
-- Check size of size_t - done
-- Choosing type for size_t - unsigned size_t
-- Choosing option for HAVE_TYPE__TIMEB
-- Performing Test _CL_HAVE_OPTION__TIMEB
-- Performing Test _CL_HAVE_OPTION__TIMEB - Success
-- Choosing option for HAVE_TYPE__TIMEB - _timeb
-- Performing Test HAVE_SYMBOL_FLOAT_T
-- Performing Test HAVE_SYMBOL_FLOAT_T - Success
-- Check size of DWORD
-- Check size of DWORD - done
-- Choosing type for _cl_dword_t
-- Check size of long
-- Check size of long - done
-- Choosing type for _cl_dword_t - unsigned long
-- Looking for printf
-- Looking for printf - found
-- Looking for strftime
-- Looking for strftime - found
-- Looking for wcscpy
-- Looking for wcscpy - found
-- Looking for wcsncpy
-- Looking for wcsncpy - found
-- Looking for wcscat
-- Looking for wcscat - found
-- Looking for wcschr
-- Looking for wcschr - found
-- Looking for wcsstr
-- Looking for wcsstr - found
-- Looking for wcslen
-- Looking for wcslen - found
-- Looking for wcscmp
-- Looking for wcscmp - found
-- Looking for wcsncmp
-- Looking for wcsncmp - found
-- Looking for wcscspn
-- Looking for wcscspn - found
-- Looking for wcsupr
-- Looking for wcsupr - found
-- Looking for wcscasecmp
-- Looking for wcscasecmp - not found
-- Looking for wcsicmp
-- Looking for wcsicmp - found
-- Looking for wcstoll
-- Looking for wcstoll - found
-- Looking for wprintf
-- Looking for wprintf - found
-- Looking for lltow
-- Looking for lltow - found
-- Looking for wcstod
-- Looking for wcstod - found
-- Looking for wcsdup
-- Looking for wcsdup - found
-- Looking for strupr
-- Looking for strupr - found
-- Looking for strlwr
-- Looking for strlwr - found
-- Looking for lltoa
-- Looking for lltoa - found
-- Looking for strtoll
-- Looking for strtoll - found
-- Looking for gettimeofday
-- Looking for gettimeofday - found
-- Looking for _vsnwprintf
-- Looking for _vsnwprintf - found
-- Looking for mmap
-- Looking for mmap - not found
-- Looking for MapViewOfFile
-- Looking for MapViewOfFile(0,0,0,0,0) - found
-- Choosing function for fileHandleStat
-- Looking for fstati64
-- Looking for fstati64 - not found
-- Looking for _fstati64
-- Looking for _fstati64 - found
-- Choosing function for fileHandleStat - _fstati64
-- Choosing function for fileStat
-- Looking for stati64
-- Looking for stati64 - not found
-- Looking for _stati64
-- Looking for _stati64 - found
-- Choosing function for fileStat - _stati64
-- Choosing function for fileSize
-- Looking for filelengthi64
-- Looking for filelengthi64 - not found
-- Looking for _filelengthi64
-- Looking for _filelengthi64 - found
-- Choosing function for fileSize - _filelengthi64
-- Choosing function for fileSeek
-- Looking for lseeki64
-- Looking for lseeki64 - not found
-- Looking for _lseeki64
-- Looking for _lseeki64 - found
-- Choosing function for fileSeek - _lseeki64
-- Choosing option for HAVE_TYPE_CL_STAT_T
-- Performing Test _CL_HAVE_OPTION_STATI64
-- Performing Test _CL_HAVE_OPTION_STATI64 - Failed
-- Performing Test _CL_HAVE_OPTION__STATI64
-- Performing Test _CL_HAVE_OPTION__STATI64 - Success
-- Choosing option for HAVE_TYPE_CL_STAT_T - _stati64
-- Choosing function for fileTell
-- Looking for telli64
-- Looking for telli64 - not found
-- Looking for _telli64
-- Looking for _telli64 - found
-- Choosing function for fileTell - _telli64
-- Choosing function for _realpath
-- Looking for realpath
-- Looking for realpath - not found
-- Choosing function for _realpath - using default
-- Choosing function for _rename
-- Looking for rename
-- Looking for rename - found
-- Choosing function for _rename - rename
-- Choosing function for _close
-- Looking for _close
-- Looking for _close((int)0) - found
-- Choosing function for _close - _close
-- Choosing function for _read
-- Looking for _read
-- Looking for _read((int)0, (void*)0, (unsigned int)0) - found
-- Choosing function for _read - _read
-- Choosing function for _cl_open
-- Looking for _open
-- Looking for _open(0,0,0) - found
-- Choosing function for _cl_open - _open
-- Choosing function for _write
-- Looking for _write
-- Looking for _write((int)0, (const void*)0, (unsigned int)0) - found
-- Choosing function for _write - _write
-- Choosing function for _unlink
-- Looking for _unlink
-- Looking for _unlink((const char*)0) - found
-- Choosing function for _unlink - _unlink
-- Choosing function for _ftime
-- Looking for _ftime
-- Looking for _ftime(0) - found
-- Choosing function for _ftime - _ftime
-- Choosing function for _mkdir
-- Looking for _mkdir
-- Looking for _mkdir((const char*)0) - found
-- Choosing function for _mkdir - _mkdir
-- Choosing function for SLEEPFUNCTION
-- Looking for usleep
-- Looking for usleep - found
-- Choosing function for SLEEPFUNCTION - usleep
-- Choosing function for _snprintf
-- Looking for snprintf
-- Looking for snprintf - found
-- Choosing function for _snprintf - snprintf
-- Choosing function for _snwprintf
-- Looking for snwprintf
-- Looking for snwprintf - found
-- Choosing function for _snwprintf - snwprintf
-- Choosing symbol for _O_RANDOM
-- Looking for _O_RANDOM
-- Looking for _O_RANDOM - found
-- Choosing symbol for _O_RANDOM - _O_RANDOM
-- Choosing symbol for _O_BINARY
-- Looking for _O_BINARY
-- Looking for _O_BINARY - found
-- Choosing symbol for _O_BINARY - _O_BINARY
-- Choosing symbol for _S_IREAD
-- Looking for _S_IREAD
-- Looking for _S_IREAD - found
-- Choosing symbol for _S_IREAD - _S_IREAD
-- Choosing symbol for _S_IWRITE
-- Looking for _S_IWRITE
-- Looking for _S_IWRITE - found
-- Choosing symbol for _S_IWRITE - _S_IWRITE
-- Choosing type for TCHAR
-- Check size of TCHAR
-- Check size of TCHAR - done
-- Choosing type for TCHAR -  TCHAR
-- Choosing symbol for _T
-- Looking for _T
-- Looking for _T - found
-- Choosing symbol for _T - _T
-- Performing Test _CL_HAVE_PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE
-- Performing Test _CL_HAVE_PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE - Success
-- Performing Test _CL_HAVE_GCC_ATOMIC_FUNCTIONS
-- Performing Test _CL_HAVE_GCC_ATOMIC_FUNCTIONS - Success
-- Performing Test _CL_HAVE_GCCVISIBILITYPATCH
-- Performing Test _CL_HAVE_GCCVISIBILITYPATCH - Success
-- Performing Test _CL_HAVE_TRY_BLOCKS
-- Performing Test _CL_HAVE_TRY_BLOCKS - Success
-- Checking support new float byte<->float conversions
-- Checking support new float byte<->float conversions - yes
-- Choosing namespace for hashmaps
-- Performing Test _CL_HAVE_STD__TR1_HASHMAP
-- Performing Test _CL_HAVE_STD__TR1_HASHMAP - Success
-- Choosing namespace for hashmaps - std::tr1::func
-- Performing Test _CL_HAVE_NAMESPACES
-- Performing Test _CL_HAVE_NAMESPACES - Success
-- Performing Test _CL_HAVE_NO_SNPRINTF_BUG
-- Performing Test _CL_HAVE_NO_SNPRINTF_BUG - Success
-- Performing Test _CL_HAVE_NO_SNWPRINTF_BUG
-- Performing Test _CL_HAVE_NO_SNWPRINTF_BUG - Success
-- Performing Test _CL_ILONGLONG_LL
-- Performing Test _CL_ILONGLONG_LL - Success
-- Performing Test LUCENE_STATIC_CONSTANT_SYNTAX
-- Performing Test LUCENE_STATIC_CONSTANT_SYNTAX - Success
-- Check for ANSI scope
-- Check for ANSI scope - found
-- Could NOT find ZLIB (missing:  ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Checking to see if CXX compiler accepts flag -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
-- Checking to see if CXX compiler accepts flag -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage - yes
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: E:/qtproject/clucene/clucene-build
```

so what argument should i enter inside cmake qt wizard to let it understand the location of the zlib and boost folders ??

Answer (score 1):

There are **two ways** (for WINDOWS):

---

**FIRST**

(for SourceForge, clucene-core-2.3.3.4.tar.gz):

---

**Dependencies**:

a) CMake (install)
b) Boost (unpack)
c) ZDLIB source, not DLL (unpack)

**Build instructions**:

1 run **CMake GUI**

2.1 Set **where is the source code** = "E:\test\clucene-core-2.3.3.4\clucene-core-2.3.3.4"

2.2 Set **where to build the binaries** = "E:\test\clucene-core-2.3.3.4\clucene-core-2.3.3.4"

2.3 Select **Boost_DIR** parameter and **set boost path** ("E:\test\boost_1_53_0\boost_1_53_0")

2.4 Click **Configure**, program will report an error (ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR), **this is normal**

2.5 Check the checkbox **Advanced** and **scroll-down** to end of parameters list

2.6 Select **ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR** parameter and **set zdlib path** ("E:\test\zdlib")

2.7 Click **Configure**

2.8 Click **Generate**, now everything should be okay

2.9 **MAKE**

---

**SECOND**

(for GITHUB, git://clucene.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/clucene/clucene):

---

**Dependencies**:

a) CMake (install)
b) Boost (unpack)

**Build instructions**:

1 Run **cmd**

2 **Set path to CMake** `Set PATH=C:\Program Files\Cmake 2.8\bin`

3.1 **Set path to Boost** `Set BOOST_ROOT=E:\test\boost_1_53_0\boost_1_53_0`

3.2 `Set BOOST_PATH=E:\test\boost_1_53_0`

3.3 `Set BOOST_BUILD_PATH=E:\test\boost_1_53_0\boost_1_53_0\tools\build\v2`

4 **Configure** using CMake: 
`cmake -G "Generator name"`

(where "Generator name" is your favorite compiler or IDE, such as "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" or just "MinGW Makefiles")

5 **MAKE**

---

Also, when you work with this engine, i recommend you add to your project(link library) two code  compiled libraries

for example:

`C:\Develope\CodeBlocks\clucene\bin\libclucene-core.dll.a`

`C:\Develope\CodeBlocks\clucene\bin\libclucene-shared.dll.a`

And also, add to your project(search directory) two path for *.h files of clucene engine source

for example:

`C:\Develope\CodeBlocks\clucene\src\core`

`C:\Develope\CodeBlocks\clucene\src\shared`